# Arquillian Cube Basic Example/Tutorial JMX Remote Access times out

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, docker, jboss-arquillian

I have tried to reproduce the Arquillian Cube Basic Example/Tutorial (on http://arquillian.org/arquillian-cube/#_basic_example), which starts a Tomcat 7 Docker Container and tries to deploy a war File in this Tomcat container.

Even though I have specified environment variables as in the tutorial

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8089     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

when i run maven with "clean test", i get the following:

```
INFORMATION: Connecting to JMX at service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8089/jmxrmi
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 51.125 sec <<< FAILURE!
org.arquillian.example.HelloWorldServletTest  Time elapsed: 51.124 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Unable to contruct metadata for archive deployment.
Can't connect to 'service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8089/jmxrmi'.
   Make sure JMX remote acces is enabled Tomcat's JVM - e.g. in startup.sh using $JAVA_OPTS.
Example (with no authentication):
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8089
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.ProtocolMetadataParser.retrieveContextServletInfo(ProtocolMetadataParser.java:82)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.remote_7.TomcatRemoteContainer.deploy(TomcatRemoteContainer.java:127)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:151)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:118)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:92)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:232)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:212)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:171)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:376)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 172.17.0.2; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2430)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:308)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.ProtocolMetadataParser.connect(ProtocolMetadataParser.java:121)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.tomcat.ProtocolMetadataParser.retrieveContextServletInfo(ProtocolMetadataParser.java:78)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 103 more
```

I have already checked, that the tomcat docker container is created, and when i use the same options to create and run it manually, the tomcat-users.xml contains the right credentials and the manager-jmx role for admin-user.

This is my arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
        http://jboxx.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/deployments</property>
    </engine>


    <extension qualifier="docker">
        <property name="serverVersion">1.32</property>
        <property name="serverUri">http://localhost:2375</property>
        <property name="definitionFormat">CUBE</property>
        <property name="dockerContainers">
            tomcat:
                image: tutum/tomcat:7.0
                exposedPorts: [8089/tcp]
                await:
                    strategy: polling
                env: [TOMCAT_PASS=mypass, JAVA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8089 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false]
                portBindings: [8089/tcp, 8080/tcp]
        </property>
    </extension>

    <container qualifier="tomcat" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="host">localhost</property>
            <property name="httpPort">8080</property>
            <property name="user">admin</property>
            <property name="pass">mypass</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.arquillian.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>cube-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>arquillian-tutorial</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.15.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.arquillian.cube</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-cube-docker</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-tomcat-remote-7</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This is the Servlet as shown in the Tutorial:

```
package org.arquillian.example;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

And this is the Test as in the Tutorial:

```
package org.arquillian.example;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.arquillian.test.api.ArquillianResource;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class HelloWorldServletTest {

    @Deployment(testable=false)
    public static WebArchive create() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "hello.war").addClass(HelloWorldServlet.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void should_parse_and_load_configuration_file(@ArquillianResource URL resource) throws IOException {

        URL obj = new URL(resource, "HelloWorld");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        assertThat(response.toString(), is("Hello World"));
    }
}
```

Can anyone reproduce the Error and tell if i missed something? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: also include the docker commands you are using

Comment: @Sebastian I'm not aware i have to use any Docker commands. I think the Arquillian cube extension takes care of that. Everything it has to know is specified in the dockerContainers-property, right? Or did you mean the ones i used to check the tomcat-users.xml?

Comment: Here you can find an example of using Tomcat to deploy an archive https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-cube/blob/master/docker/ftest/src/test/java/org/arquillian/cube/servlet/HelloWorldServletTest.java

Comment: [Edited] Thank you, i already managed to run this example and will go on from there and discard the example i posted here. It works, when i use Docker image "tomcat:7.0.75-jre8" but i need it to use "camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest" which uses tomcat 8.0. Even when i switch to "camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:7.3.0" which uses tomcat 7.0 i get an "org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.Deploym‌​entException: Unable to deploy an archive hello.war" caused by Caused by: "**java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server**"

Comment: I think it has something to do with "await: strategy: polling." Arquillian tries to deploy before the tomcat is ready. With "await: strategy: sleep sleepTime: 1s" i got it to work. Now I'm looking for a more elegant solution for the await-strategy than sleeping for 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

This await-strategy did the job for me on a Tomcat:

```
  await:
                strategy: log
                match: 'Server startup'
                stdOut: true
                stdErr: true
                timeout: 300
                occurrences: 1
```

It searches the logfile for "Server startup"